# read from hdfs write to kafka using scala spark,but get NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to read text file from hdfs using spark rdd,and write to kafka by foreach.Code as follow

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val kafkaItemProducerConfig = {
      val p = new Properties()
      p.put("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVER)
      p.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      p.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      p.put("client.id", KAFKA_ITEM_CLIENT_ID)
      p.put("acks", "all")
      p
    }
    val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("esc")
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    kafkaItemProducer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](kafkaItemProducerConfig)
    if (kafkaItemProducer == null) {
      println("kafka config is error")
      sys.exit(1)
    }
    val dataToDmp = sc.textFile("/home/********/" + args(0) +"/part*")
    dataToDmp.foreach(x => {
      if (x != null && !x.isEmpty) {
        kafkaItemProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](KAFKA_TOPIC_ITEM, x.toString))
      }
    }
    )
    kafkaItemProducer.close()
  }
```

I'm quite sure the KAFKA_SERVER and KAFKA_ITEM_CLIENT_ID and KAFKA_TOPIC_ITEM is correct.But it got a error:

```
 ERROR ApplicationMaster [Driver]: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 12 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 12.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 18, tjtx148-5-173.58os.org, executor 1): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at esc.HdfsWriteToKafks$$anonfun$main$1.apply(HdfsWriteToKafks.scala:56)
    at esc.HdfsWriteToKafks$$anonfun$main$1.apply(HdfsWriteToKafks.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1954)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1954)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:341)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It said

```
    at esc.HdfsWriteToKafks$$anonfun$main$1.apply(HdfsWriteToKafks.scala:56)
    at esc.HdfsWriteToKafks$$anonfun$main$1.apply(HdfsWriteToKafks.scala:53)
```

So,there is an error in 56 line

```
kafkaItemProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](KAFKA_TOPIC_ITEM, x.toString))
```

53 line is

```
dataToDmp.foreach(
```

I checked the dataToDmp has content,I used `dataToDmp.take(100).foreach(println(_))` to check,and it is correct.

Is there some error in my code?

Comment: I would add an assertion about your kafka producer on line 56, as you're instantiating it at the top level (which is executed within the master nodes) and then using it within the function in the foreach, which is serialized and then distributed for execution on the executor nodes.

I'm surprised you didn't receive a serialization exception tbh. 

A common Spark workflow when making external connections for each RDD is to only instantiate the connection/producer within the function.

Comment: The producer could be null if you're running this code on a cluster. You should be using `dataToDmp.forEachPartition`, then creating a new producer per partition

Comment: It works! I changed that I used foreachpartition method instead of foreach.In each partion,I creat a producer.Thank you @LiamClarke ,@cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your advice! It worked!!

Comment: @LiamClarke .I move the KAFKA_SERVER and KAFKA_ITEM_CLIENT_ID and KAFKA_TOPIC_ITEM definition in main,and  as you say,I receive a serialization exception.At beginning ,the KAFKA_SERVER and KAFKA_ITEM_CLIENT_ID and KAFKA_TOPIC_ITEM definition is out side of main,but in object class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked .I changed that I used foreachpartition method instead of foreach.In each partion,I creat a producer.
The code as below:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    var kafkaItemProducer: KafkaProducer[String, String] = null

    val KAFKA_ITEM_CLIENT_ID = "a"
    val KAFKA_TOPIC_ITEM = "b"
    val KAFKA_SERVER = "host:port"

    val kafkaItemProducerConfig = {
      val p = new Properties()
      p.put("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVER)
      p.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      p.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      p.put("client.id", KAFKA_ITEM_CLIENT_ID)
      p.put("acks", "all")
      p
    }
    val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("esc")
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)



    val dataToDmp = sc.textFile("/home/****/" + args(0) +"/part*",5)
    dataToDmp.foreachPartition(partition =>{
      val kafkaItemProducer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](kafkaItemProducerConfig)
      partition.foreach(
        x=>{ kafkaItemProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](KAFKA_TOPIC_ITEM, x.toString))
          Thread.sleep(100)
        }
      )
      kafkaItemProducer.close()
    })

  }
```